# How to add input to a dynamically created form?

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a form that displays a number of TextInputs based options selected in a previous screen. Inputs can range from 1 to 12. As far as I know, the state represents one input. How do I get values updated and displayed `{text}` on my form? Here is a look at the code I have. I need to update the `description` of each input.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TextInput} from 'react-native';


const MyFunction = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  let tempArray = [
    {
      day: 'Monday',
      description: '',
    },
    {
      day: 'Tuesday',
      description: '',
    },
    {
      day: 'Wednesday',
      description: '',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <View>
      {
        (tempArray.length > 0) && (
          <View>
            <Text>{text}</Text>
            <TextInput
              placeholder
              onChangeText={(text) => setText(text)}
              defaultValue={text}
            />
          </View>
        )
      }
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyFunction;
```

Comment: Is input text fields are dynamically generated? Are you generating using condition based

Comment: Yes, as shown, it dynamically created and it is based on the days added to the array.